# SqlConnection and TransactionScope Timeout

Tags: timeout, transactionscope, sqlconnection, msdtc

I have a TransactionScope (over DTC, read committed) with a timeout of 60 minutes.
In the TransactionScope I have opened the connection (I hope to enlist in the transaction) but after 30 seconds I get a timeout.

In the machine.config I changed the system.transaction maxTimeout to 60 minutes.

Why does the timeout occur after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

A SqlCommand already has a CommandTimeout property that defaults to 30 seconds. May be you are using it within your transaction.