# Timeout exception when using NHibernate TransactionScope

Tags: nhibernate, timeout, castle-activerecord, sqlexception

This is continuation of [Timeout exception when timeout set to infinite time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844327/timeout-exception-when-timeout-set-to-infinite-time) (and I also see unanswered [SqlConnection and TransactionScope Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752440/sqlconnection-and-transactionscope-timeout) question).

I am using CastleProject ActiveRecord over NHibernate, C# 3.5. I have multiple subsequent inserts to a database within TransactionScope. One of them (random, different each time) fails with TimeoutException. Whichever timeout I set in my config file (10 hours), this does not matter. If I do not use transaction scope, it work (but too slow). It seems, NHibernate transaction has default timeout 30 second and is not affected by hibernate.command_timeout value.

Is it correct? How to overcome this?

Comment: Which TransactionScope are you using? ActiveRecord's or .NET's?

Comment: I am using ActiveRecord TransactionScope.

Comment: I tried your advise to use command_timeout instead of nhibernate.command_timeout and now I got a new exception "Transaction not connected or was disconnected".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing your connection time out value?

Include "Connection Timeout=somehighvalueinsecondshere" in the connection string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx